# return a binary list elements between two lists based on a condition

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following two lists:

```py
A = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
B = ['b', 'd', 'f', 'g']
```

Of which I want to check if elements of `B` are in `A`then `0` else `1`. The expected output should be like this:

```py
{'C': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]}
```

I tried the following but didn't get what I am expecting.

```py
{'C': [int(i == j) for j in A] for i in B}
```

Comment: `[int(x in A) for x in B]` should do it.

Comment: @Mathieu I think you meant `[int(x in B) for x in A]`. And of course if you do `set_b = set(B)` and change it to `[int(x in set_b) for x in A]`, it'll be much faster, especially with larger lists because checking if something is not in a list requires iterating over the entire list, but sets perform that operation much faster.

Comment: Whatever you're actually trying to do, you might want set operations instead, for example `set(A) & set(B)` is the set union: `{'g', 'b', 'f', 'd'}`

Comment: @Boris Thank you for the correction. Indeed transforming the list to set would be more efficient if the list were large. I doubt there is much of a difference for 10-ish elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

as @Boris mentioned using `set(B)` would be much faster if its a long list.

```
{'C': [int(value in set(B)) for value in A] }
```

output :

```
{'C': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]}
```

Answer (score 2):

As per your expected output (If A element is in B):

```
[1 if x in B else 0 for x in A]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
A = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
B = ['b', 'd', 'f', 'g']

C = [1 if a in B else 0 for a in A]
```

This is a one liner achieving what you are looking for. Nice and simple.